# How do I view a Function List from my open file or project in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I frequently use Notepad++ for source code editing on my Windows machine. If I go to View --> Function List I can have it show a list of all the functions in the files I'm working in, so I can click on one and jump to that location.

I just started using the Code::Blocks IDE now for C++. Does it have something similar, or a plugin that can do this? I've searched around, googled a bit, and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Should be in the Symbol Browser.  [Go here and search on the page for symbol view.](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html)

Comment: Solved; thank you. I've never used a "real IDE" before, as people put it. I didn't think it would be called "Symbols." Apparently someone thinks I'm an idiot so I got a downvote. You answered my question.

Comment: Probably just a knee-jerk response to a question that could have been solved with a websearch... If you knew what words to use in the search. I think it's a "Class View" even when there are no classes in Visual Studio. In Eclipse it's "Outline" and "Project Explorer", if you expand the Project Explorer far enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment below my question answered it. Thank you. In Code::Blocks it's not called a "Function List," it's simply called "Symbols." It never occurred to me it would be under that name. Click the "Symbols" tab on the left-hand side, select "Current File's symbols" under the "View" dropdown menu, and select "Global functions." Then, you see the functions listed below. Double-click them to jump to any desired function's location.

Boom done. That's all I wanted.

See here:

[image]

Also, see this image here, from @Fibbles. He posted it as a link in the comments below. Click where he marked "Here" to get a function drop-down list, in alphabetical order, as an alternate way to jump to a function.

[image]

### Update 22 Apr. 2020:

I use Eclipse now, and highly recommend it, and have written full setup instructions in a PDF here. Check it out:

1. See the PDF in this GitHub project and folder: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse.

   1. Direct link: [Eclipse setup instructions...pdf](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/eclipse/Eclipse%20setup%20instructions%20on%20a%20new%20Linux%20(or%20other%20OS)%20computer.pdf)

Comment: There's also a drop down box from which you can quickly access functions. [See here.](http://i.imgur.com/YdRdSA2.png)

Comment: Hey! How 'bout that! I'll be a coder in no time. Only 1500 hrs or so in and I've already learned a new trick. :) Thanks. +1

Comment: @Fibbles, how did you insert that link like you did so that you could share that image with me? In comments, I can't make a picture paste, though in the main answer I could.

Answer (score 1):

When you install CodeBlocks, you should get the option "Custom".

**Select All Plugins** iis where you will find that there are some useful plugins for you. Or you can go to **Plugins->Manage** plugins to show the plugins management panel.

You will find plugins it has installed automatically and from there you may install what you need.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but possibly can be salvaged by adding which plugin the OP needs to install.